# wxWidgets: control or dialog to chose directory path

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

What is the  way to choose a directory path (by browsing) with wxWidgets and save it as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wxWidgets land, they call the dialog box a file chooser:
[wxFileDialog](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxfiledialog.html#wxfiledialog)

There are also examples of how to customize it.

Comment: thanks. sibling of wxFileDialog - wxDirDialog is more suitable for me since I do not need listings of files.